# Can JSON be used with MySQL for Android?

Tags: android, json

Am I able to use JSON with a MySQL for my database, in an Android application, for data retrieval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreeing with Chris, this link may help...

[Json object Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

I am using this in a project i am working on where my application sends data to a mysql database with json.

This link also helped me out a little bit:

[Example of json with java](http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/)

Comment: I also found a few questions here on SO that helped out a lot, but i never bookmarked them or have them referenced and can not seem to find them. GL

Comment: thanks. i'm trying to create an application that retrieves the longitude and latitude of an event then displays where the event is and once clicked shows further detail from the database regarding that event.

Comment: In a class that i had recently we had to do something very similar to that. We were using QT and C++. GL HF.

Comment: does qt allow you to program for android? on the website it dosn't say android is supported

Comment: I do not believe so. It wasn't for the android. I forgot to mention that, it was for something else. Sorry if that created confusion.

Comment: no problem. so with json would it be possible for me to "grab" a long and lat coordinate and display it on a map?if i can do that i'm happy :)

Comment: Yes. json is basically a means to encode objects into strings to make it easier to transfer/receive the data. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/x-andbene1/?ca=drs-    If you scroll down to the json section it will explain a little more what json is used for.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking, no you cannot.  MySQL will not run on an Android device.  Android supports SQLite which is a file-backed SQL database for storage.  If you want to use MySQL on some server some where and transmit JSON data to your application, then yes, you can do that.  You'll need to clarify a bit before I can give you a better answer.

Comment: ...but yes, you can store JSON to SQLite all right. SQLite sets no explicit limitation on the length of text you put into a text column.

Comment: sorry about the confusion. your second part is what i'm looking for. the mysql database is on a server and i want to use json to transmit the data to the app

Answer (score 0):

here is a nice article  http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php/.  hope you like it, and if you have any question, you can ask, i will try to solve it as soon as possible.